# Как заставить видеть iPhone сразу весь блок целиком (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css

## Код:

1. Имеется блок со строго заданной шириной (800px).
2. В шапке пишем `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`.

## Тест:

1. Заходим с Android (samsung-browser и chrome-browser), видим отображение блока на всю ширину дисплея:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Заходим с iPhone 7 (safari-browser), видим отображение блока лишь на ширину самого дисплея iPhone 7, чтобы увидеть весь блок, нужно руками уменьшить масштаб:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Вопрос:

Как заставить iPhone по умолчанию отображать блок на всю ширину (как на Android), без дополнительных телодвижений (уменьшения масштаба руками)?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Однажды одна маленькая строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал семь
  своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и пустился в дорогу.
</div>
```

Comment: @St1myL можно пример кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена жестким выставлением ширины `viewport`:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=800px">
```

Проверил, работает на Android и iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

### Решение

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
```

> [Документация](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) Apple.

Comment: Опробовал, теперь и Android перестал отображать сразу весь блок. на iPhone ничего не изменилось.